# Mongodb - Get back object instead of array from find

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
db.users.find();
```

Will return me an array of users:

```
[{
_id: 123
name: bob
},{
_id: 456
name: tom
}]
```

I need to map users to another collection by the id, so I would like to get an object back from mongo where the keys are _id and values are the user doc.

i.e.

```
users = {
123: {_id: 123, name: bob},
456: {_id, 456, name:tom}
}
```

Then I can access users directly from that object without having to iterate an array to find specific users.

```
id = 123;
user = users[id];
```

Comment: there isn't a way to get data back this way from mongod except by using mapreduce which is not very fast/efficient...  of course it can write the results into a new collection so that might save you a step.

Comment: I'd suggest you just build a quick client-side index by looping through the returned results. It should be super fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get an object like this one from mongodb, but it's quite easy to build it yourself:

```
db.users.find(function (err, docs) {
  var users = {};
  docs.forEach(function (doc) {
    users[doc._id] = doc;
  });
  do_whatever_you_want_next(users);
});
```

Comment: Yeah that is not too bad. Was messing with aggregate and $project to see if I could get it.

Comment: Is it still not possible in latest version of mongodb ?

Comment: @mandeep_m91, I don't think It'll ever be a part of MongoDB API.

Comment: 3 years later but I'm looking exactly the same, Do you know if mongo / mongoose support this by default?

Comment: 6 years later and still looking this functionality, lost lots of time trying to do it with aggregation group, project and mapreduce with no success, it's a pitty to have to rework the resutls taking in account that mongo has already worked them

Answer (score 1):

Posting my solution in a more modern syntax:

```
    const pushSubscriptions = await PushSubscription.find({ token: { $in: tokens } }).exec();
    const userTokens = pushSubscriptions.reduce(
        (result, ps) => {
            result[ps.token] = ps;
            return result;
        },
        {});
```